# Merge dictionaries without overwriting previous value where value is a list

Tags: python, dictionary, merge

I am aware of [Merge dictionaries without overwriting values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12121417/merge-dictionaries-without-overwriting-values), [merging "several" python dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9415785/merging-several-python-dictionaries), [How to merge multiple dicts with same key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5946236/how-to-merge-multiple-dicts-with-same-key), and [How to merge two Python dictionaries in a single expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-can-i-merge-union-two-python-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression).

My problem is slightly different, however.

Lets say I have these three dictionaries

```
dict_a = {'a': [3.212], 'b': [0.0]}
dict_b = {'a': [923.22, 3.212], 'c': [123.32]}
dict_c = {'b': [0.0]}
```

The merged result should be

```
result_dict = {'a': [3.212, 3.212, 923.22], 'b': [0.0, 0.0], 'c': [123.32]}
```

This code here works, but would nest lists within the lists

```
result_dict = {}
dicts = [dict_a, dict_b, dict_c]

for d in dicts:
    for k, v in d.iteritems():
        result_dict.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
```

Using `extend` instead of `append` would prevent the nested lists, but doesn't work if a key doesn't exist yet. So basically it should do a `update` without the overwriting, as in the other threads.

Sorry, it was a mistake on my side. It was too late yesterday and I didn't notice the line that threw the error wasn't the one I thought it did, therefore assumed my dictionaries would already have the above structure.
In fact, `mgilson` was correct assuming that it was related to a `TypeError`. To be exact, an 'uniterable float'.

Comment: Could you explain why `extend` won't work?  Shouldn't `setdefault(k, [])` take care of the nonexistent key problem?

Comment: why did the result list for `a` end up in that order?  I would have expected:  `[ 3.212, 923.22, 3.212]`

Comment: @mgilson Yes, sorry. I already sorted in my head. But it should be the way you said.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that `.extend` works here ...

```
>>> dict_a = {'a': [3.212], 'b': [0.0]}
>>> dict_b = {'a': [923.22, 3.212], 'c': [123.32]}
>>> dict_c = {'b': [0.0]}
>>> result_dict = {}
>>> dicts = [dict_a, dict_b, dict_c]
>>> 
>>> for d in dicts:
...     for k, v in d.iteritems():
...         result_dict.setdefault(k, []).extend(v)
... 
>>> result_dict
{'a': [3.212, 923.22, 3.212], 'c': [123.32], 'b': [0.0, 0.0]}
```

The magic is in the `dict.setdefault` method.  If the key doesn't exist, `setdefault` *adds* a new key with the default value you provide.  It then *returns* that default value which can then be modified.

---

Note that this solution *will have a problem* if the item `v` is not iterable.  Perhaps that's what you meant?  e.g. if `dict_a = {'a': [3.212], 'b': 0.0}`.

In this case, I think you'll need to resort to catching the `TypeError: type object is not iterable` in a `try-except` clause:

```
for d in dicts:
    for k, v in d.iteritems():
        try:
            result_dict.setdefault(k, []).extend(v)
        except TypeError:
            result_dict[k].append(v)
```

Comment: I haven't been following all the stuff in `abc`.  Is there anything which is basically "scalar", i.e. "not iterable, or iterable but a string"?

Comment: @DSM -- Not sure I get you question.  Not sure I get OP's question.  Everything in OP's sample input is iterable, but OP said that `.extend` wouldn't work for some reason which made me think that OP had tried it (though maybe not).  So, I started grasping for a reason *why* `.extend` may have failed.  A non-iterable item seemed to be the most likely culprit... (but just a guess).

Comment: I only mean that the TypeError approach won't prevent scalarlike but iterable objects, such as strings, from taking the `.extend` branch and turning `"Fred"` into `"F", "r", "e", "d"`.

Comment: Ahh ... You're referencing the fact that `str` has no `.__iter__` function?  Fortunately python3.x fixed that problem ... and I think that strings are the only object commonly treated as scalars that are also iterable...

Comment: Man, I'm not doing a very good job of explaining myself. :^)  No python 3 connection, only that this code will work for scalar number values but won't work for scalar strings, and I was wondering if there was some clever trick other than `not isinstance(v, basestring)` that I was the last one to hear about, like usual.

Comment: @DSM -- Nope, no trick (other than `hasattr(v, '__iter__')` on python2.x).  If you want to treat strings like scalars, then you need to special case it.

Comment: @mgilson Good assumption. I edited my first post. It was indeed a `TypeError`. Your solution works fine, but what I don't get is, if I try that in the interpreter, it gives me `KeyError`, when I try to do `result_dict['foo'].append(3.14)`. Could you explain why this is? It seems to work in my Python script.