# How to merge/concat 2 dicts into a tuple?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

i'm having troubles to find a solution to this :

```
dict_a = {'deecf4bc': 'my_machine'}

dict_b = {'deecf4bc': 'blade-000'}

dict_ab = {'deecf4bc':'my_machine', ' : ', u'blade-000'}
```

This is a print of my dicts with this :

```
for key, value in dict_X():
print(key, ' : ', value)
```

Those dict came from Python libraries like Nova or Ironic
I want to create a dict from 2 others based on the first column and I failed hard, I have tried this :

```
x = dict(a.items() + b.items())
```

and many more

Someone suggested this : [How do I merge two dictionaries in a single expression in Python (taking union of dictionaries)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-do-i-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression-in-python-taking-union-o)

It doesn't work as it display the same as dict_b

EDIT : As I was rewriting the dicts, it appears to me that the final form of data that I want is something like one key and 2 values, it it possible ?

Thank you

Comment: Those aren't dictionaries, but tuples of strings. Are you sure that this is what you have? Can you show the actual code where they are defined?

Comment: `dict_a` is not a `dictionary` but `tuple`

Comment: To actually merge two actual dicts, see this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-do-i-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression-in-python-taking-union-o?rq=1

Comment: I have added precisions for this

Comment: Sorry, it's actually this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20509570/merge-dictionaries-without-overwriting-previous-value-where-value-is-a-list

Answer (score 0):

To merge dictionnaries:

```
dict_ab = dict_a | dict_b #Python3.9+

dict_ab = {**dict_a, **dict_b} #Python3.5+
```

Answer (score 0):

looking at your edit note, to group together the values of 2 dict you can do the following

```
>>> a={i:i*10 for i in range(5)}
>>> b={i:i*100 for i in range(5)}
>>> a
{0: 0, 1: 10, 2: 20, 3: 30, 4: 40}
>>> b
{0: 0, 1: 100, 2: 200, 3: 300, 4: 400}
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> c=defaultdict(list)
>>> for d in [a,b]:
        for k,v in d.iteritems(): #d.items() in py3+
            c[k].append(v)

        
>>> c
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {0: [0, 0], 1: [10, 100], 2: [20, 200], 3: [30, 300], 4: [40, 400]})
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to join two dictionaries in a way that the values of the joined dictionary consist of the tuple of all values of the corresponding input dictionaries having the same key, you could say:

```
dict_ab = dict((k, (v, dict_b[k])) for k,v in dict_a.items())
```

with the data from the question, this gives:

```
>>> dict_ab
{'deecf4bc': ('my_machine', 'blade-000')}
```

A more generic way, working with any number of dictionaries:

```
def zip_dicts(*dicts):
    return dict((k, tuple(d[k] for d in dicts)) for k in dicts[0])
```

Example:

```
>>> zip_dicts(dict_a, dict_b)
{'deecf4bc': ('my_machine', 'blade-000')}
```

The keys are taken from the first dictionary and must be present in all others.